# Firebase - Update specific fields simultaneously without replacing all of the data

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I would like to be able to publish simultaneously in two directories of my Firebase database. I created a function for this, according to the example proposed in the "Update specific fields" section of the [Firebase Javascript documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write):

```
  function linkTwoUsers(user1, user2) {

    // The two users are "connected".

    var user1Data = {
        userLink: user2
    };
    var user2Data = {
        userLink: user1
    };

    var updates = {};
    updates["/users/" + user1] = user1Data;
    updates["/users/" + user2] = user2Data;

    return database
      .ref()
      .update(updates)
      .then(() => {
        return res.status(200).end();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return res.status(500).send("Error: " + error.message);
      });
  }
```

The problem is that when I run the function, instead of uploading the directories, it replaces all the data present in it.

Here are the user directories before the function:

[image]

And then:

[image]

How do we make sure the data doesn't overwrite the others? Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you get the solution for this object data structure to update a filed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to narrow your path to just the property you are trying to update:

```
updates["/users/" + user1 + "/userLink/"] = user1;
updates["/users/" + user2 + "/userLink/"] = user2;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though you're creating an entirely new object when you set:

```
 var userData = { someThing: stuff }
```

When you pass that in, it will override the original object. One way you might solve this (there might be a more efficient way) is to grab the objects from Firebase, add the new property and value to the object, then send the entire object back into Firebase.

In some javascript frameworks, you should be able to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to set all of an object's props to another object like this:

```
 var newObject = { ...originalObject }
 newObject.userData = "something"
 // then save newObject to firebase
```

Comment: I had indeed thought of this solution. I use Firebase Function, do you think it is compatible?

Comment: This isn't really the most efficient way to perform a multi location update, because you have to read then write.  If you just want to write, only indicate the specific fields you want to update in your multi-location update.  Stradopshere's answer shows that.

Comment: I am unable to comment on Stradosphere's answer, but it is indeed the efficient way to perform this task.